# HTTP request freezes when I run the program, but not when I step in

Tags: vba, excel, http

the program runs from an excel workbook,takes a list of values, builds a query string and passes it to this chunk of code

```
Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlHttp.Open "GET", connectionstring, False
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
xmlHttp.send

Dim html As Object
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.ResponseText
```

This is part of a loop, so it gets executed many times.
If I step into the code and execute it line by line there is no problem, but when I run it it freezes on the xmlHttp.send line, not at the first loop, but somewhere in the middle of the loop (around the 10th execution maybe).
Do I have to tell it to wait for soething in particular?
Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `DoEvents` or `Application.Wait` just after the `Send` command?

Comment: What should I set the wait to?
A random number of seconds? Is there a way to tell it to wait until the request is received?

Comment: I would suggest DoEvents first. For `Wait`, set to 1 second for the first try `Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))`, I don't know how many time you loop so you need to take that pause time into account for execution (i.e. 1sec * 1000 loop = 16-17min so it is growing fast!). I don't know if XMLHTTP has a property `Ready_State` like IE...

Comment: Apparently there is one : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753800(v=vs.85).aspx , use `Do While xmlHttp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop`

Comment: This might be what I was looking for! I'll try and come back to you! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! ;) If it is, I'll do a proper answer so that you can close the subject! ;)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Please write an answer and I'll pick it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XMLHTTP has a `ReadyState` property  like IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753800(v=vs.85).aspx) :

So this is how to use it :

```
xmlHttp.send
Do While xmlHttp.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```